# Why does meltwater taste different?

Tags: water, home-experiment, taste

I've noticed that water obtained from melting ice cubes (by keeping them in the open) tastes different from water cooled to the same temperature.

Furthermore, the taste goes away if you keep it in the open for a sufficient duration of time.

I can think of these possible explanations:

- Dissolved gases being released
- Something to do with the crystal structure of ice
- Something to do with dissolved minerals

The Internet is giving me all sorts of varying answers.

Exactly what chemical differences exist between meltwater and cold water?

Comment: I might guess the dissolved gases (and specifically the chlorine/chloramine) would be ejected faster from melted ice (and slowly from standing water), but I don't know if that's the taste you're looking for.

Comment: @NickT: I'm not looking for the taste, I'm looking for all the physical/chemical differences. The taste is just a point proving the _existence_ of those differences. You can make that into an answer, though I'd prefer something more than a "guess" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I read it had to do with dissolved gasses, that "normal tasting" water has the dissolved gas but freezing water you lose the gasses.  So I tried this home experiment.  I froze water then let melt and tasted it, it tasted bad with the off flavor.  Then I took out a large freezer bag and only put a small amount of the foul tasting water.  I then shook it violently for some time to mix air back into the water.  Boom the water tasted fine again.  No double blind here but seriously is it needed?

Comment: Interesting experiment. Did the normal taste return because new gasses where introduced into the water or did some gases (oxygen?) escape from the water?

Answer (score 3):

Oxygen solubility is 10 mg/L for water, and 14.5 mg/L for ice. Even after the ice melts to room temperature, the oxygen level in the melted ice water remains higher than the water that kept a constant room temperature(~12 mg/L vs 10 mg/L). The extra oxygen present is most likely the cause for the difference in taste.

Comment: Complete nonsense. The oxygen solubility in water rises towards 0°C (14.6mg/l, 9mg/l at 20°C), and drops to practically zero upon freezing.